# AutoCAD plug-ins for labeling

Tags: autocad-plugin

I need to label numerous block individually.
Is there a possibility in AutoCAD to write a code
that will find each individual block and write a label on it?

Answer (score 0):

In LISP you can try this:

```
(vl-load-com)

(defun GetThisDrawing ( / ) 
    (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object) )
)

(defun GetActivespace ( / space ) 
    (setq space (if (zerop (vla-get-activespace (GetThisDrawing)))
    (if (= (vla-get-mspace (GetThisDrawing)) :vlax-true)
      (vla-get-modelspace (GetThisDrawing))
      (vla-get-paperspace (GetThisDrawing)))
    (vla-get-modelspace (GetThisDrawing))) )
)

(defun C:MarkBlock (  / BlockName filter blocks sl i % Position msg label )
    (setq BlockName "name_of_your_block")
    (setq filter (list (cons 0 "INSERT") (cons 2 BlockName) ))
    (setq blocks (ssget "X" filter) )
    (setq sl (sslength blocks))
    (setq i 0)
    (repeat sl
        (setq % (vlax-ename->vla-object(ssname blocks i) ))
        (vlax-get-property  % 'InsertionPoint )
        (setq Position (vlax-get-property  % 'InsertionPoint ) )
        (setq msg (vlax-get-property  % 'Name ) )
        (setq label (vlax-invoke-method (GetActivespace) 'AddMText Position 0 msg ) )
        (setq i (1+ i ) )
    )
)
```